# Unable to confirm complete sending of data from server side to client side in C

Tags: c, sockets

I am new to socket programming in C. I have written a server-side program and a client-side program. Their functions are described below:

Server side : The server sends integers from 1 to 9 to the client side, and after sending 9, it sends 0. Once 0 has been sent successfully to the client, the server is supposed to print (and NOT send) "SENT DATA SUCCESSFULLY" on the terminal window running server-side, which is a confirmation of the fact that the server has sent 1 to 9 and then 0 successfully to the client.

Client side: The client side is supposed to display all the integers sent by the server. Since we know that we are going to receive integers from 1 to 9 and then 0, the expected output at client side should be :

`1 --> 2 --> 3 --> 4 --> 5 --> 6 --> 7 --> 8 --> 9 --> 0`

I try to achieve this using below code:

Code for client side:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/types.h>

#include <unistd.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>

int main()
{
    int client_socket;
    client_socket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    struct sockaddr_in server_address;
    server_address.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server_address.sin_port = htons(8080);
    server_address.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    int connection_status = connect(client_socket, (struct sockaddr *) & server_address, sizeof(server_address));

    char data_recv;           //'data_recv' variable stores the data received from server
    recv(client_socket, &data_recv , sizeof(data_recv), 0);  //receive data from server
    while(data_recv - 48)            //receive 1 to 9. Once 0 is received, the loop breaks.
    {
        printf("%c --> ", data_recv);
        recv(client_socket, &data_recv , sizeof(data_recv), 0);
    }
    printf("%c\n", data_recv);        //print 0 
    close(client_socket);             //close client socket

    return 0;
}
```

Code for server side :

```
#include <stdlib.h>

#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/types.h>

#include <unistd.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>

int main()
{
    int server_socket;
    server_socket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    struct sockaddr_in server_address;
    server_address.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server_address.sin_port = htons(8080);
    server_address.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;

    bind(server_socket, (struct sockaddr *) &server_address, sizeof(server_address));

    listen(server_socket, 5);
    while(1)
    {
        int client_socket;
        client_socket = accept(server_socket, NULL, NULL);
        for(int i = 1; i < 10 ; i++)             //first sending integers from 1 to 9
        {
            char c = i + 48;                    //performing integer to character conversion
            send(client_socket, &c, sizeof(c), 0);    //sending data to client
        }
        char c = 48;                      //store 0 in c (ASCII value of 0 is 48)
        send(client_socket, &c, sizeof(c), 0);  //send 0 to client
        printf("SENT DATA SUCCESSFULLY");       //print the message
    }
    close(server_socket);      //close the server socket
}
```

The problem : On the terminal window which runs the client side of this program, I get the following output :

`1 --> 2 --> 3 --> 4 --> 5 --> 6 --> 7 --> 8 --> 9 --> 0`

So, on the client-side, we can clearly see that 0 has been received. This means that the server has sent all the data successfully to the client.

However, the problem comes in the terminal window running server-side of the program. Since we know that the server has already send 0 (from the output on the terminal window of client-side), the terminal window on the server-side should display "SENT DATA SUCCESSFULLY". However, it is not displaying this message ("SENT DATA SUCCESSFULLY"). The terminal of server-side remains blank, without displaying the above message, even though 0 has been successfully sent to the client.

I wanted to know :

1. Why does the terminal window on server-side does not display the message
       "SENT DATA SUCCESSFULLY" ?
2. How can this be fixed ?

Thanks for helping me !

Comment: Add a newline to your `printf`: `printf("SENT DATA SUCCESSFULLY\n");`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

printf() does not add a newline, so the text is printed, but you won't see it as the shell normally outputs text only when it sees a newline character.

So either add a newline:

```
printf("SENT DATA SUCCESSFULLY\n");
```

(Note the \n in the string)

or flush the output, e.g. using the fflush(3) function, when you don't wan't a newline character.

Comment: It would be good to explain why that is needed.

Comment: The terminal is usually in a mode, where it outputs text only after seeing a newline character (google for raw vs. cooked mode of Unix shells).

Comment: I know that. But since you are providing an answer it would be good to have that in your answer as well as how to flush in situations where one really doesn't want a newline.

Comment: Good idea.  Edited my answer.

Comment: Thanks for help. I was unaware of this fact.